# Compiling Rcpp code gives segmentation fault

Tags: rcpp

I would like to trace a segmentation fault in my Rcpp code.  To do so, I would like to implement a "main" C++ function and run my code with GDB.  But I cannot make this main function work.  Here is a minimal example:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    Rcp::NumericVector i;
    return 0;
};
```

I used the flags used by Rcpp to compile the code: `g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I"/home/login/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include" -fpic -g -ggdb -O0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-6WVosl/r-base-3.3.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -c main.cpp -o main.o`

Then `g++ -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o main main.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR -g -ggdb -O0`

(I have tried several flavours: removing `fpic`, `-Wl`.)

Running `main` gives me a segmentation fault.

GDB backtrace gives me

```
#0  0x00007ffff78f5ac5 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libR.so
#1  0x00007ffff78f6a17 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libR.so
#2  0x00007ffff78f70ad in Rf_allocVector3 () from /usr/lib/libR.so
#3  0x0000555555556856 in Rcpp::Vector<14, Rcpp::PreserveStorage>::Vector (this=0x7fffffffe1e0) at /home/login/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/vector/Vector.h:58
#4  0x00005555555560ec in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe2f8) at main.cpp:7
```

Valgrind suggests `Invalid read of size 8` at the same place.

Any suggestion would be welcome.

g++ is `(Ubuntu 6.3.0-12ubuntu2) 6.3.0 20170406`.  Computer is `Linux XXX 4.10.0-38-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 10 13:24:27 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

Comment: You misunderstand and misconstruct a few things, but I think in general you want to look more closely at [RInside](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html).

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks.  Very nice project as well.  However, my aim, if possible, is to debug with GDB some Rcpp code that is part of a larger R package.  Embedding some R in C++ would not here, right?

Comment: You. Cannot. Compile. Rcpp. Classes. Without. R.  Your `main()` above simply won't work. Rcpp is _an R extension_.

Comment: OK!  It is unfortunate for me.  Thanks!  (Will not help me to debug me code, yet !)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply cannot use `gdb` on a `main()` for Rcpp code with an underlying R session: *all* R objects require R.

So either debug your package from R with gdb -- as [described in Section 4.4 of Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-exts.html#Debugging-compiled-code) or use [RInside](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html) if you really think you need a main.

You *can* use `gdb`.  Just not how you tried.